# Testing that an ajax request hasn't been made in angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, angularjs

How can I go about testing that an ajax request hasn't been made when using angular `$httpBackend`. I've tried using `verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` but (in v1.1.5 at least) it never seems to cause a test to fail.

#### More details of the scenario

My database module uses ngResource to connect to my server side database. I've set it up so that GET all is cached client side so only the first call to my `getTable('tableName')` method should fire an ajax request. So the test in question needs to verify that the first call makes an ajax request but the second one doesn't

Comment: Do people vote to close solely because a question is phrased as 'What's the best way to... '. This is clearly not an opinion question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting your test to fail when a request is made that shouldn't be, just make sure that you don't define an `expect` method for it. Angular will throw an error if it gets a request that wasn't expected.

You have to write an `excpect` method for each request that is made, so you would have one `expect` for the first call to `getTable` that should actually make the request, and then if for some reason, a request is attempted after that, Angular will throw an error and your test will fail.

So the body of your test would look something like this:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET("request_url");
getTable("tableName");
$httpBackend.flush();
//no error because it was expecting a request
getTable("tableName"); //will throw an error if it actually tries to make a request
```

Comment: I've put some more details of my use case in the question. I'm not sure if what you say can be applied here

Comment: I think my problem is probably that I'm using $httpBackend's `when` methods alongside its `expect` ones. On re-reading the docs I should choose one or the other depending on what exactly I'm testing.

Comment: Yeah, if you have a `when` mapped to this url, you'll never get an error, since it fulfills multiple requests, whereas the `expect` does not. It took me a few times through the $httpBackend documentation to understand what each is doing.